# "Complex" grouping and indexing in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a problem to which I can't seem to find a simple solution.

I want to achieve the following:
* i have a list of tasks, each with an owner and a due date
* i want to display a list of all tasks grouped by owner
* i want to sort the owners based on the due dates: e.g. The owner with the lowest due date first, followed by the owner with the second lowest, etc
* I want to be able to paginate the results, preferable with will_paginate

To ilustrate, this would be a result i am looking for:

Harry
- task 1, due date 1
- task 3, due date 4
Ben
- task 2, due date 2
Carol
- task 4, due date 3

So far, I can query for all owners with tasks, sort them on a virtual attribute with their "earliest due date" and then display them *and* their tasks in a view.

There are multiple problems with this approach, imo:
* i run multiple queries from the view (owner.tasks.each etc). I always learned that running queries from the view is bad
* i'm doing the sorting by loading all records in memory (virtual attribute), which could get problematic with large records set.
* I have no idea how i can get pagination in on this, that will be sensitive to the amount of tasks displayed

I can't seem to crack this nut, so any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!
Erwin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query, you have not provided sample data (ideally using SQL) so that we could play ourselves:

```
SELECT
u.id as owner_id, u.name as owner_name, t.id, t.due_date
FROM users u
INNER JOIN tasks m ON u.id = m.owner_id
INNER JOIN tasks t ON u.id = t.owner_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, t.id, t.due_date
ORDER BY MIN(m.due_date), t.due_date
```

You should get all the data you need in the proper order, and you can paginate simply by applying `LIMIT` to it (or converting it to AR and submitting it to will_paginate).

Comment: This is the kind of solution i was looking for: everything in 1 query. I tried it out and doesn't quite work though: the results array contains objects that only contain the task.id and the task.due_date, not the owner_id..

Comment: You probably should alias `u.id` as `owner_id`, as `id` is also used for task ID (I will edit the code).

Comment: You are 100% right, that returns what I want. I am abit of an SQL n00b (as you probably already figured out by now). How would I 'convert this to AR'? What i mean: this query returns the fields specified under SELECT only, how would i convert it so the results array contains the full task objects? Thx a ton for your help

Comment: Well, the problem with GROUP BY is that you need to have listed in GROUP BY every column that you want in SELECT list. So you can do that for each column from `tasks` (prefixed by `t.`). However, I am not that proficient with ActiveRecord, so probably there's a more Rails-idiomatic way to do that, you'd be best off asking another question about translating above query to AR. You'll get an upvote from me for sure as I'd be interested in good answers as well. :)

Comment: Deleted my previous comment, as it turned out not to be that simple. Asked my follow-up question here: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5543792/using-rails-ar-to-generate-this-complex-query)