# Using Rails/AR to generate this complex query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, orm, activerecord

In trying to solve a grouping and ordering problem (original question here: ["Complex" grouping and indexing in rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5541055/complex-grouping-and-indexing-in-rails)), I got a SQL query that will fetch the right records the right way.

My question now is: **how do I generate this SQL query using Rails/AR synthax?**

The SQL-query is as follows:

```
SELECT
u.id as owner_id, u.name as owner_name, t.id, t.due_date
FROM users u
INNER JOIN tasks m ON u.id = m.owner_id
INNER JOIN tasks t ON u.id = t.owner_id
GROUP BY u.id, u.name, t.id, t.due_date
ORDER BY MIN(m.due_date), t.due_date
```

Comment: `INNER JOIN tasks m ON u.id = m.owner_id
INNER JOIN tasks t ON u.id = t.owner_id` - this can't be right, what is it supposed to do?

Comment: What it boils down to is that i want to sort a parent class based on an attribute of its child class. This query tried to take a different approach grouping (by parent class) and sorting (by attribute) the child class. Either way would help me.

Comment: Your comment triggered me to rephrase the question here [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5544416/how-do-i-sort-a-parent-class-based-on-an-attribute-of-the-child-class)

Comment: @Jonas: Check out the original question, it's a way to get records sorted by minimal due_date of user's tasks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll need to play around with your database and these attributes to get it just right, but you could try something like this.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :next_task, :class_name => :task, :order => "due_date desc", :limit => 1
   has_many :tasks, :order => "due_date desc"

end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user

end

User.include([:next_task,:tasks]).order("task.due_date desc").tasks.each { |task|
      puts task.user.owner_id 
      puts task.user.owner_name
      puts task.due_date
}
```

I'm not sure about the order clause to sort the users... you'll have to inspect the SQL generated to determine exactly what needs to be there.

Comment: `include` will not generate `INNER JOIN`, it will generate `LEFT JOIN`. Use `joins` instead.